# Change Rundeck storage password

Tags: rundeck

Is there any way to change the storage password for an existing Rundeck installation? This is the password referred to in `rundeck-config.properties` as `rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.password` and `rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.password`.

I presume it would be a case of going through each stored item, decrypting with the old password, encrypting with the new password, and finally updating the config file, but I'm hoping there's already a tool/script to do this.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must follow these steps for your projects:

1. Export projects ([this](https://github.com/G3NSVRV/Rundeck-Scripts/blob/master/Scripts/export_projects_zip) script looks useful for do that massively on ZIP file).
2. Delete all projects. (if you like, via [RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/commands/#projects) or [API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#f9ce661b-3f0b-a2b5-d71d-a5667cca97a9)).
3. Stop the Rundeck service.
4. Change the encrypt passwords in the `rundeck-config.properties` file.
5. Start the Rundeck service.
6. And later import projects (if you like, via [RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/commands/#projects) or [API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#694811c0-5406-76ee-6ba4-f5f0f30ae647)).

Now your projects are encrypted with your new password. About the keys, you need to recreate it again.

**Advice**: test before in some non-prod environment.